Getting 'source not available' when analysing .dmp file (symbols loaded), but think the source is attached?

So the main executable is at the top, and it has user code 'yes' and symbol status 'symbols loaded'. However I am getting 'source not available' after running 'debug with native only'.
also here is the minidump summary:

am i missing something in having the source code correctly attached? any advice appreciated, thanks.
